# PyQt5 port: how do I hide a window and let it appear at the same position

Tags: python, pyqt4, porting, pyqt5

I'm porting a PyQt4 program to PyQt5. One part of it is hiding the window, taking a screenshot of the area behind the window and showing the window again, which worked just fine with PyQt4.

With my PyQt5 port, everything works fine, but the window appears on the position where it was when the program was started, and not at the position where it was before calling the hide() method.

I'm testing this on a Linux box. The relevant code strips down to:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget,
                             QGridLayout, QPushButton)

class demo(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        mainWidget = QWidget(self)
        layout = QGridLayout(mainWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

        self.testButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.testButton.setText('Test')
        self.testButton.clicked.connect(self.hideMe)
        layout.addWidget(self.testButton, 0, 0)

    def hideMe(self):
        self.hide()
        QTimer.singleShot(300, self.showMe)

    def showMe(self):
        self.show()
        self.move(self.pos())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = demo()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In showMe(), self.pos() actually contains the right coordinates, but the window isn't moved there (but to it's "original" position it had right after starting).

When I e. g. do a self.move(10, 10) instead, the window is actually moved there. But as soon as I use a variable (I also tried to save the x and y of self.pos in a variable and to use this instead) the window is shown at the position it had after starting.

Why does a move() call with integers actually move the window, but a move() call with variables doesn't? How do I move the window to the position it had before hiding?

Thanks for all help!

Edit (perhaps to find out what's the difference):

The very same code using PyQt4 works:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget,
                         QGridLayout, QPushButton)

class demo(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        mainWidget = QWidget(self)
        layout = QGridLayout(mainWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

        self.testButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.testButton.setText('Test')
        self.testButton.clicked.connect(self.hideMe)
        layout.addWidget(self.testButton, 0, 0)

    def hideMe(self):
        self.hide()
        QTimer.singleShot(300, self.showMe)

    def showMe(self):
        self.show()
        self.move(self.pos())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = demo()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

so why behaves Qt5 different to Qt4 in this case?

Comment: print `self.pos()` in `hideMe` and `showMe` and see difference.

Comment: That's the point: there's no difference here!

Comment: @TobiasLeupold. It would be helpful if you stated which linux distro you are using, and also which window manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in Qt5 the geometry won't be re-set if it is exactly the same - but I don't know why this behaviour has changed, or whether it is a bug. And note that it is not just the position that is affected - resizing is also ignored.

Here is a hack to work around the problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMargins

class demo(QMainWindow):
    ...

    def hideMe(self):
        print('hide:', self.geometry())
        self.hide()
        QTimer.singleShot(300, self.showMe)

    def showMe(self):
        print('show1:', self.geometry())
        hack = QMargins(0, 0, 0, 1)
        self.setGeometry(self.geometry() + hack)
        self.show()
        self.setGeometry(self.geometry() - hack)
        print('show2:', self.geometry())
```

**UPDATE**:

After some further investigation, it seems there is a much simpler solution. If the window's geometry is explicitly set before the window is first shown, it won't move back to its original position after a subsequent hide()/show(). In which case, no other hacks/work-arounds are needed.

Comment: This actually does the trick. But it does seem like a bug to me indeed! I'll investigate this and file a bug if it's not a feature ;-) Thanks!

Comment: This can be produced with a "real" C++ Qt program as well, so I think this is really a bug. I posted a report about this at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56579

Comment: @TobiasLeupold. I have found a much simpler solution that works for me - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your further investigation. I'll update the Qt bug as well.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed seems like a bug.

Other workarounds could be setting the `QWindow` position instead of the widget's, like:

```
windowHandle()->setPosition(windowHandle()->position());
```

or setting the WA_Moved attribute before `show()`:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_Moved);
```

I think ekhumoro's answer is the best. If you're going to use a workaround better make it explicit, rather than an implicit hack.

Comment: That's not in dispute. The problem is *moving* the window afterwards. The OP was able to do `show(); move(pos())` in qt4, but that doesn't work in qt5.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I use `self.old_pos` in `hideMe` and `showMe` then it works for me (Linux).

```
def hideMe(self):
    self.old_pos = self.pos()
    self.hide()
    QTimer.singleShot(300, self.showMe)

def showMe(self):
    self.show()
    self.move(self.old_pos)
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it doesn't change anything here. Also, it would be nice for me to find out why the Qt4 version works (see my edit of the original post), and the Qt5 version doesn't (which only differ by the import statements).